# Custom group user in aem, page contents not displayed using editor.html

Tags: aem

I created a custom group user. I have logged in as this custom user in the localhost:4502 instance. I have given read,delete, modify, create permissions of content to this user, but it does not have replicate permission. While trying to see the page contents using editor.html it shows "Internal Server Error. Cannot serve request to /editor.html/content/geometrixx/en/products/square.html in /libs/granite/ui/components/foundation/form/field/field.jsp". Following is stack trace

```
16.09.2015 18:17:45.313 *ERROR* [127.0.0.1 [1442407665253] GET /editor.html/content/en.html HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl service: Uncaught SlingException
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.jsp.libs.cq.gui.components.common.pathbrowsers7.render_jsp._jspService(render_jsp.java:203)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:449)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.callJsp(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:284)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.access$100(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory$JspScriptEngine.eval(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:536)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:361)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:171)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:463)
    at com.adobe.granite.ui.components.ComponentHelper.call(ComponentHelper.java:664)
    at org.apache.jsp.libs.granite.ui.components.foundation.form.field.field_jsp._jspService(field_jsp.java:249)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
```

I can see the page contents using content finder cf#.

Can someone help me out on this.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Hi this is the message in the error log

Answer (score 3):

Double check the user permissions you've created that the user has read access to /etc/cloudservices/scene7. There is a deny:all acl on the /etc node that might be interfering with you.  The pathbrowser7 component attempts to resolve the /etc/cloudservices/scene7 resource and if the user does not have access to this node then you'll end up with a NullPointerException.

Just wondering why you didn't add your user to the content-authors group which would give the user the correct permissions to author content. IIRC the user would then have read access to /etc/cloudservices/scene7.  As a best practice I would avoid creating custom ACLs for users and try to stick to AEM's groups, and customize from there if needed.

Comment: Thanks Ben. Now we are creating cusom groups using the out of the box groups. your suggestion was really helpful.